# How does SSL work? Isn't there a hole?

Tags: security, encryption, ssl, ssl-certificate

I was reading [this article](http://luxsci.com/blog/how-does-secure-socket-layer-ssl-or-tls-work.html), specifically the "SSL in action" part. It says:

> When Client connects to company.com on its SSL-secured port, the company sends back its public key (and some other information, like what Ciphers it supports).
>   ...
>   Once the client is happy with the server (and the server with the client, if needed), then the client choose an SSL Cipher to use from the list of encryption methods provided by the server, and generates a “symmetric key” (password) for use with that Cipher.  The client encrypts this password using the server’s public key and sends it back to the server.  The server (and only the server) can decrypt this message and get this password, which is now shared by both the client and server.

So, my understanding is that there is only *one* public key; the one that is given to company.com by the trusted 3rd party (thawte/godaddy/verisign etc). The client then chooses to accept this key/certificate and then sends a password used to encrypt future communications.

If there is only one public key, then can't a hacker just go that site once, get a copy of the public key, then intercept the client as he sends the password, decrypt it using the public key he already has, and then spy on all future communications? What prevents that?

The part I don't understand is

> The server (and only the server) can decrypt this message and get this password

Why can only the server decrypt the message? What prevents others from decrypting it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Public Key is one way. You can not decrypt the communication with it. You need the private part of the key pair to do the decryption.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_key for a really good description.

Comment: Thanks for that link. This was going to lead me to my next question... if the client can encrypt things, why can't he deduce an algorithm to decrypt it? Aren't all mathematical relationships reversible (plus/minus, multiply/divide, power/log), *unless* information is thrown out (non 1-to-1 relationships) such as in hashing? But I guess this sentence explains it "They are based on mathematical relationships (most notably the integer factorization and discrete logarithm problems) which have no efficient solution." But technically, we could produce the private key from the public key...

Comment: ...it's just that it would take a ridiculous amount of time (several lifetimes I'm guessing)?

Comment: Exactly. I'm sure a sharp mathematician could give you something more specific, but given limited computer resources (As in, you don't have a 10000 node Linux cluster) There is no hope to do the calculations needed in a reasonable amount of time (as in, the time left before the sun is a charcoal briquette) Of course as computing power increases, perhaps it will be more feasible, but you will always run into cost/benefit problems. Even if you have the super computer, you have to make more money with the hack than it cost to set up the system and run it.

Comment: @Bill Heller Charcoal briquette is no joke, [according to Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/ssl/ssl-information-center/ssl-basics/index.html#a2) at current computer processing speeds an attacker (with a single PC presumably) would need 1 trillion years to crack a 128 bit encrypted SSL session.

Comment: And just in case you think I was exaggerating... "Given all of today's computing power and available time — even a billion computers doing a billion checks a second — it is not possible to decipher the result of strong cryptography before the end of the universe." -from: http://www.pgpi.org/doc/pgpintro/ under the heading "Strong Cryptography"

Comment: And if you theoretically do figure out the key, well it is relatively easy to rotate to new keys. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange

Comment: Thanks @Amazed, was looking for good references. @Ralph. It's just hard for people to even comprehend the size of the numbers involved. Computers are fast, but you very quickly run into the limits of the size of the number that a computer can handle in normal variables. After about 2^64 (a 20 digit number) you are left trying to manipulate string representations of the numbers which will really slow you down. The keys are 2^256 (78 digit numbers), theoretically you could count the number of atoms in the universe with a number that big.

Comment: You would never use string representations, but that does not really matter to the speed. you would create a custom struct, or use something like bignumber.