# Is the data sent from web server to browser is really more secured in https than http?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, internet-security

I was just reading about the differences between http and https briefly. And what I have not understood is the following possible scenario:

Everyone has SSL public key right?

So, anyone can get the public key from a web server and then use it to decrypt the messages sent from the web server? This way, if the web server sends any secret information, the intruders can know that, right?

I understood that private key is with the web server, so only the web server can decrypt the encrypted message (using public key) send by the browser. And so the data sent from the browser is secured. But I doubt if the data received from the web server is really secured.

Or let's say if the public key changes from user to user. But the intruder can hack it when the browser sends it for the first time right?

Please correct me if I understood it wrong.

EDIT:
Okay, I think I get it from the description provided by the questioner in this link:

[How does SSL work? Isn't there a hole?](https://superuser.com/questions/309450/how-does-ssl-work-isnt-there-a-hole?rq=1)

It says:

> When Client connects to company.com on its SSL-secured port, the
>   company sends back its public key (and some other information, like
>   what Ciphers it supports). ... Once the client is happy with the
>   server (and the server with the client, if needed), then the client
>   choose an SSL Cipher to use from the list of encryption methods
>   provided by the server, and generates a “symmetric key” (password) for
>   use with that Cipher. The client encrypts this password using the
>   server’s public key and sends it back to the server. The server (and
>   only the server) can decrypt this message and get this password, which
>   is now shared by both the client and server.

It means that the client won't encrypt just with the public key he has, but uses a password that he generated (symmetric key) which will be shared with the web server using the public key encryption. And only the web server can know the password shared by the client, as only he owns the the private key part. So, both the web server and the client uses the symmetric key to encrypt messages, which no one knows or can intrude.

Am I right?

Comment: Too many questions in one post.

Comment: @moab it's just a single question

Comment: I see 8 question marks (including title), it is not a single question.

Comment: @Moab Have you read the question..those question marks are just an expression..but my question is only one.

Comment: Disagree, they are questions which could have possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting a better idea, but think of it this way.  Encryption tends to use a public key and a private key, both are used to unlock it and the only one that is known is the public key.  The private key tends to be stored with the SSL certificate, so no one knows the key used to decrypt the messages.  This secures the messages going both ways, and unless using a vulnerability, it's impossible for someone to tell what is being sent back and forth.  Vulnerabilities tend to involve malware or a fake SSL certificate, but you can google that to find out more about those kind of issues.

What i think you should also know, is that encryption isn't full-proof, and can be broken depending how strong the key is.  A good example is the SuperFish (i think that's the right name) that Lenovo was involved with a few months ago, they were using an SSL Certificate that would override the certificate for other websites.  This just means it was using their SSL certificate for secure access to various sites, but the problem was the private key had an easy to guess password.  They didn't have to break the algorithm, because the company used the company name for the password (komodia).  Now any computer using those superfish certificates were no longer secure, as anyone could decrypt the messages and see what information was being sent back and forth.  The only obstacle would be to get access to the traffic, but that's another topic.

That isn't common, but most sites use strong keys that can take many tens to hundreds of years before it's broken (without having the password).  If you want to know about what makes the certificates strong or not, you can google that as well.  Does that clear up any other confusion?

Comment: Thanks. Last time when I read about Lenovo's superfish, I didn't know what I was reading.

Comment: I don't think the Superfish private key was weak; it was just that its passphrase was included in the malware installed on the Lenovo machines. This password was needed to create fake certificates for whatever website one was visiting, allowing Superfish to inject ads in those pages.

Comment: Think of it this way, the password for the private key is the company name that used Superfish, which was a pretty easy to guess password (it didn't take long for people to figure it out either).  That's the same as leaving the key for an impregnable door, under the door mat.  That makes it weak/easy to break into.  I'm not saying the algorithm used was weak, but either of the two can make a private key weak (algorithm or password).

Comment: ... *"the private key was weak and when it was broken, it used an easy to guess password"* suggests otherwise, I feel. That said, I feel the main problem was *distributing* the private key and its passphrase (plus installing their own root certificate in the OS)...

Comment: True, i could fix the wording on that, but distributing isn't a problem if the password is easy to guess.  People have a bad habit of being lazy with passwords, so they use something easy to remember that they are familiar with (check Ashley Madison top 10 passwords).  In this case, it wouldn't matter how many people distributed it, because they found it by guessing instead of breaking the algorithm.  If journalists and security experts can guess the password, it would be easy for any bad guys to guess it (who do it for a living).

Comment: ...but you're using the Superfish example in a question about HTTPS. I don't think that's a relevant example. In regular HTTPS one **cannot** get to the private key (so even a private key without a passphrase still yields secure communications in HTTPS). Superfish is not about weak keys, it's just malware (which itself got compromised for above-mentioned reasons). Any computer running malware can see everything a user does, or can fool a user into thinking they're connecting to some web server while they are actually connecting to some other server—all unrelated to key strength of HTTPS.

Comment: I think you need to go research more about superfish and HTTPS. This will help you understand HTTPS better http://robertheaton.com/2014/03/27/how-does-https-actually-work/ and i'm not a fan of Forbes, but this is a great article about Superfish http://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2015/02/19/superfish-need-to-know/.  Read both articles and figure out what's wrong about your comment.  You will see how Superfish actually works, and why it relates to HTTPS.

Comment: Hmmm, I think *you* need to read that, or need to rewrite the statements in your answer. But well, I don't really care.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is the higher version of HTTP, it specially created for Secured Transaction between Client and Server.
This Connection works on either SSL or TLS Communication Protocols and both the Protocols uses `Asymmetric` Public Key Infrastructure System. An Asymmetric System uses two keys (public/Private) for encrypt/decrypt Data. When a Client Request for a Page to any Server Sends two things with Response to the Client - which are a Public Key and a Certificate, whenever again communication is done on this channel at that time Server Encrypt/Decrypt Data using Private Key and Browser has its Public Key to Encrypt/Decrypt Data.

You have Question that is it possible to Hack these Keys?

In my Opinion, It is Possible.

At this time there are a lot Algorithms to Encrypt and Decrypt Data/Keys. For Example take an Algorithm [**`SHA`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm) which has many versions and Improving itself day by day.  For more information about `SHA3` visit this [Link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) So if Intruder Hacks the Public Key but it is not possible to Decrypt it by them with out `SHA key` using which Key is Decrypted. (What i have learnt from google) because `SHA-3` **24** rounds of Encryption on a Data with a Key. Somewhere I had read that **SHA-3** is more powerful than other Algorithms. So if any Intruders have Public Key on Hand than they can not decrypt its Data directly, they need another with which these Keys (Public/Private) are Encrypted. Data is Encrypted By the Keys, and Keys are also Encrypted by another Key which is not shared on any Platform, either it is Client or Server. if any Changes in these Keys are Made than it will be identified by the Server and for Data also. Because Some how it generates a Hash Code using which it can be identified. See this How **SHA** works,
[image: Secure Hash Algorithm Mechanism]

HTTPS is the More Secure connection till this Day and every Site who are required for Secured Transaction are uses HTTPS Connection only between Clients and Server.

In Conclusion if Key is not Protected by Intruder than this Algorithm can identify changes in the Data. Thats why it is possible for Secured Connections.

Hope this will Help you to understand what exactly going on behind this Scene.